# SSAS Error : The following system error occurred: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

The administrator changed the password of the administrator user domain due to a new security policy, and since that day the SSIS and SSAS fails. I changed the user acount of SQL Services with a new User configured as an administrator, I also changed Imperonation Information of the Data Souce in the SSAS project.

the Control flow task error message:

```
[reception [1]] Erreur : « System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [08S01] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Socket closed.
   à System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   à System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
   à System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
   à System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   à System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   à System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
   à Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedHelper.GetManagedConnection(String assemblyQualifiedName, String connStr, Object transaction)
   à Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManager100.AcquireConnection(Object pTransaction)
   à Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.AcquireConnections(Object transaction)
   à Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostAcquireConnections(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Object transaction) »
```

the Analysis Services Processing Task error message:

```
Error : The following system error occurred: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. . 

Error : Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'DW', Name of 'DW'.

Error : OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'domain\user'; 28000;
```

Comment: Did you check the login information in your connection managers in SSIS packages?

Comment: Could you please provide information about where your packages are stored and how they are being executed?  Also, are you using configurations in your packages to set credentials in the data sources?

Comment: is "domain/user" in the ssas error the actual error message or did you replace to hide client info?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz : They are stored on the local server, and I execute them on SSIS project with debugging button, The package was created on an old server, I copied the project on a new one after disabling the protection level of the package and everything works fine until the changing of the doamin administrator password

Comment: @BillAnton : I replace it to hide info

Comment: @SlimBou are any of the services running under the admin account?  Perhaps the SSIS, SSAS services need to be restarted with the updated password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works, I forgot to change the CreatorName of the project on the server.

Answer (score 1):

**RE: SSAS Error Message**

> I also changed Imperonation Information of the Data Souce in the SSAS project.

What did you change it to?

If you are using "*impersonate service account*" and changed the service account for SSAS, then you probably just need to provide read permissions to that user on the data source (DW).